# Como fazer login e cadastro Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, html5, aplicação-web

Pessoal amanhã preciso fazer uma tela de login e cadastro de usuário,usando a conta do Facebook,preciso pegar os dados e enviar para webservice. Só que não estou conseguindo

Comment: Poste o código que você já fez. Assim podemos ver qual o erro e qual a melhor solução.

Comment: Tem documentação detalhada aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web?locale=pt_BR e o seguinte exemplo completo: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web?locale=pt_BR#example

Comment: Se ainda estiver a procura, dá uma olhada nesse [vídeo](https://celke.com.br/artigo/como-criar-sistema-de-login-com-facebook-e-php) há tutorial e o código pronto.